# Selecting elements of a vector for which a matrix satisfies a condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, logical-operators

I have two vectors with equal number of elements. These are called `x` and `y` and have `N` elements. I want to keep the elements of the vectors for which a the condition `S(x(i),y(i))>0.1` holds.

For example, if `S(x_i , y_i)` is less than `0.1`, I want to remove `x_i` and `y_i` from vectors `x` and `y`, respectively. `x_i` and `y_i` are the values of the `i`th elements of the vectors.

How can I do this?

Example:

```
x=[1,3,2,3];
y=[2,4,1,3];
```

In this example, the code should check `S(1,2), S(3,4), S(2,1), S(3,3)`.
Consider `S` to be

```
S=[1,3,4,5;
   1,3,4,5;
   1,2,0,0.001;
   12,21,2,5]
```

Then the new values of the vectors are:

```
xnew=[1,2];
ynew=[2,1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create an "elimination array". Loop over all `x,y` pairs, check the corresponding entry in `S` and set elimination to `true` if the condition is fulfilled. Then, at the end, remove all elements which should be eliminated.

```
x=[1,3,2,3];
y=[2,4,1,3];

S=[1,3,4,5;1,3,4,5;1,2,0,0.001;12,21,2,5];

% Preallocate to no elimination taking place
eliminate = zeros(size(x),'logical');
for ii = 1:numel(x)  % Loop over all elements
   if S(x(ii),y(ii)) < 0.1  % If the condition holds
       eliminate(ii) = true;  % Set elimination to true
   end
end

% Remove elements to be eliminated
x(eliminate) = []
y(eliminate) = []

x =
     1     2
y =
     2     1
```

A one-liner to do this a bit more elegant

```
eliminate = diag(S(x,y))<0.1;
x(eliminate) = []
y(eliminate) = []
```

`S(x,y)` creates a matrix of where `x` and `y` are considered to be permutable, i.e. it will be 4x4 in this example. We only need the pairs you present, which will be on the diagonal of this matrix; use `diag()` to obtain those. Then, do the logical check with `<0.1` and finally use the same removal trick as above.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as follows:

1. Build a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2) from `x` and `y` to select the desired entries of `S`.
2. Compare those entries with the threshold. That gives a [logical index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3) that you can use into `x` and `y`:

```
x = [1,3,2,3];
y = [2,4,1,3];    
S = [1,3,4,5; 1,3,4,5; 1,2,0,0.001; 12,21,2,5];
linear_ind = x + (y-1)*size(S,1);
logical_ind = S(linear_ind)>0.1;
x_new = x(logical_ind);
y_new = y(logical_ind);
```